# How to add image file to mp3 on Mac?

Tags: mac, apple-music, mp3

How can I add a picture to the mp3s I have downloaded on my mac? I add an image in apple music but it just doesn't carry over into the actual file. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So if you had a file of a bunch of songs and imported them as an album into apple music, you would actually create a separate folder with the album's name (the one you created when dropping the zip into aplle music) and this folder would have all of the updated album covers in it.

For example:

If we have a folder with songs in it called "Songs-20 hours" and imported it by dropping it into the albums section of apple music and called it "Favorite Songs", we would now have 2 files in finder. One would be called "Songs-20 hours" and one would be called "Favorite Songs". The "Songs-20 hours" file would contain all of the original artwork for the mp3s and the "Favorite Songs" file would contain the same artwork that you have in apple music. The mp3 files' artwork will also update as you change the artwork by using Show info, artwork, change artwork.

I hope this helps!!

this answer may also answer you question from a few years ago @aitía

Comment: While this may work for Apple Music, it does **not** add a picture to an MP3 file as such.

Answer (score 0):

An MP3 file is a container that, as well as MP3 format audio, can contain an image. You can find apps that will combine an MP3 audio only file with an image to produce a new MP3 containing both audio and image.

I have used [MediaHuman Audio Converter](https://www.mediahuman.com/audio-converter/). If it recognises the MP3 track, will automatically add a suitable low-res image. But you can add your own image.

There are likely other apps just as good, if not better.